# Calculate and write down order number of data on a column to another column on google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sql-order-by

I want to give order number of row depending on data on a column and write it to another column on google sheets.

[Here is my example data;](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yEThl.png)

I want sheets to calculate order by ascending the data on col L and write it to col M.

Comment: Can you please expand on what you want?  Are you trying to sort the data, or just generate a sequence based upon the order of the data?

Comment: Generate a sequence based upon the order of the data. Pardon my English I hope this is more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the function I needed;

https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267310?hl=en

RANK.EQ(A10, A1:A100, TRUE)

RANK.EQ(B32, B8:B47, FALSE)

RANK.EQ(A10, A1:A100)